# Sqlite3 PHP "database disk image is malformed"

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a sqlite db file which is definitely not corrupt since I can open it with SQLiteStudio.
However, when I try to open it dynamically with PHP with the following code I found in some tutorial:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('../testDB');
  }
}
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

$sql ="SELECT * from testTable";

$ret = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) )
{
   echo "ID = ". $row['id'] . "\n";
   echo "NAME = ". $row['name'] ."\n\n";
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
```

I get the following result:

```
Opened database successfully 
Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: Unable to prepare statement: 11, database     disk image is malformed in test.php on line 52

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in     test.php on line 53
```

I found some threads like that one, but none of them had a definite answer.
Can somebody help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `../testDB` is the correct path?

Comment: And if it is the correct path to a file, are you sure that file is a SQLite database? (Also, check to see it's not a SQLite v2 database.)

Comment: Yes, that is the path (when I change the path, it gives a different error because it doesn't find the file) and yes, it is SQLite v3 because the SQLiteStudio reads it in that format.

Comment: Maybe PHP uses some older SQLite3 version? There were couple of format-related changes in SQLite3 series. Check: SELECT sqlite_version(); in both PHP and SQLiteStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I've already the same problem with small SQLITE db.

Try to use:

```
$sql = "VACUUM";
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Would you mind extending the answer little more for fellow programmers to understand how this helps to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same "database disk image is malformed" error and i solved it using SQLiteStudio. 
Since you already have it, open the file, right click on the database and try the Vacuum option. After doing this, try the integrity check. If the result is 'OK' then your problem is solved. At least that's how i solved it. Vacuum rebuilds the entire database.